# Difference of List and ArrayList in declaration?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, declaration, array-difference

Is there a difference between these two? If so, what is it?

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: This question has been asked so many times!

Comment: People can see that there are dup questions and an answer with 2 votes but they still want to post another answer, geez...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first declaration lets you program to interface. It ensures that later on you can safely replace `ArrayList` with, say, `LinkedList`, and the rest of code is going to compile.

The second declaration lets you program to the class, so you could potentially use methods of `ArrayList` which do not implement the `List` interface. For example, you can call `ensureCapacity()` on the list declared as `ArrayList`, but not on a list declared as `List`. Although generally programming to interface should be preferred, there is nothing wrong with doing it if you must call class-specific methods: for example, ability to call `ensureCapacity()` could save some unnecessary reallocations if you know the new target size of your list.

Answer (score 0):

The former is preferred. It allows changing the implementation without changing code that depends on the field.

In *Effective Java,* Joshua Bloch says:

> If appropriate interface types exist, then parameters, return values, variables and fields should all be declared using interface types.
>
> ...
>
> If you get into the habit of using interfaces as types, your program will be much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you code to interfaces then you can change the implementation without much hassle

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you can make x now point to a LinkedList or any other implementation of List with only one line of code. If you need a specific method that is in ArrayList then having ArrayList on the left hand side is perfectly acceptable. 99 times out of 100 thought you wont so List is preferred

Answer (score 0):

With `ArrayList` you can specify an `intitalsize` and so ArrayList has `trimToSize()` method to trim its size to the current size.With `List<Integer>` you won't be able to trim the size unless you cast it back to `ArrayList`